# Chemicals Dying Light

Tags: dying-light

I've been playing a lot of Dying Light, and my favourite item is the Explosive Throwing Star. One problem: I don't have enough Chemicals for crafting the stars. Where can I find mass amounts of Chemicals in the Slums and Sector 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loot the town, there is a lot of them. Especially in homes.

Comment: You can also get supplies from the Quartermaster once a day.  This will occasionally include Chemicals.

Comment: Also, if you have a smartphone, you can download the [Dying Light Companion App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.techland.dyingLight.CA&hl=en_GB) and collect Chemicals through that. Once you decide to, you can collect your rewards from the Quartermaster too.

Comment: These good comments could have also just been edited into this answer. Why not just edit?

Comment: You're not supposed to add content to another user's answer without it being a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter the sewers in Old town, there will be two doors that require lock picks to open. In one of them, the left one i believe, has three chemicals on a shelf. Collect them, leave, then enter again, and they should have respawned.